# Pandas: Average values in groups of X days

Tags: python, pandas

I want to Average the value of AAPL.High in groups of 10 days (JAN/01 to JAN/10), using the day number 10 as the reference number.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')
```

The Idea of the code is approximately:

```
df1['demand'] = df1.groupby(['supplier_name', 'date'])['difference'].transform('mean').fillna(0)
```

Comment: Could you show us what the dataset looks like?

Comment: This is the dataset: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv

Answer (score 0):

Simple case of define index as the dates then just use `resample()`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df.resample("10d").agg({"AAPL.High":np.mean})
```

**output**

```
            AAPL.High
Date    
2015-02-17  130.657501
2015-02-27  129.675001
2015-03-09  126.661251
2015-03-19  127.134283
2015-03-29  126.533333
... ...
2017-01-07  119.532001
2017-01-17  120.841248
2017-01-27  125.740000
2017-02-06  133.172500
2017-02-16  135.899994
```